# Regex to validated 10 occurrences of comma separated numerical values

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate text field to accept only numbers. There can be 0 through 10 occurrences of numbers separated by commas.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
/^[0-9]$(?:[,][0-9]){0,9}$/i
```

this validated the comma separated numerical values, but not restricting it to 10 occurrences.

sample inputs : 1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010

can someone show me the mistake?

Comment: 1. You were rather close, except for that first `$`! 2. `[,]` is a class consisting of only 1 character; 3. the flag `i` stands for "ignore case", which adds a bit of processing time but is not useful for a string consisting of only digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
/^(\d+(?:,\d+){0,9})?$/
```

This will also accept blank string as valid input.

Comment: this is fine, but only 0-9 can be inserted as inputs. if I enter two digits or more, it will be invalidate

Comment: Yes above regex will only allow digits `0-9` only as `\d` is same as `[0-9]`

Comment: Also can you provide some valid examples of input.

Comment: sample inputs: 1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010

Comment: thanks, but this invalidates blanks, when I click on a record n load it to the text field